# wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) when trying to create an object in rails console using Parse_resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parse-platform

I'm using Parse_resource seen here https://github.com/adelevie/parse_resource and 
I'm getting the following error when trying to create an activity object in rails console:

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
>     from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/parse_resource->7851169f01ba/lib/base.rb:74:in `belongs_to'

My input is

```
activity = Activity.create
```

my activity model is:

```
## activity.rb

class Activity < ParseResource::Base    
  belongs_to :fromUser, :class_name => 'User'    
  belongs_to :toUser, :class_name => 'User'   
  fields :product, :type   
 end
```

My user model is :

```
## user.rb

class User < ParseUser    
  has_many :activitys, :inverse_of => :fromUser    
  has_many :activitys, :inverse_of => :toUser   
  alias :email :username    
end
```

It must be related to the associative properties of these models.Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of `alias` method, you missed the `,`.  Do this

```
 alias :email , :username
```

Comment: thats not it, I believe it does not make a difference for alias actually, that code was working before I added the has_many and belongs_to associative code!